# Unidentifiable metal bracket part I received with my tandem bicycle which didn't come with instructions.

Tags: parts

Can anyone identify this part and where and how it goes[image] before the bike buckles under us when being ridden

I know its not a bottle holder as I have already installed those.
Looks like a guard for something that has two screws close to one another

Comment: Derailleur guard, intended to protect the rear derailleur from impacts, many cheap bikes without break away dropouts use them as to avoid tweaking the frame from an impact with a tree, stone etc. Some people think they work others do not.

Comment: @NateWengert That's an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 5):

It's a rear derailleur guard.

Their effectiveness is often [discussed on here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10621/does-a-rear-derailleur-guard-provide-effective-protection).